# Print message with Maxima

Tags: maxima

Is it possible to make Maxima print some message on the terminal?

For example make Maxima write something like `Done with step n` in order to know where it is in the program.

Comment: According to the online documentation, page 35, print is a function you can call http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima.pdf

Comment: There is `print` as Mark mentioned. See also `printf`.